# Magento2 : ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am trying to add custom jquery code into my module but it is not working.

**app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/js/my.js**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

**app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Custom_Module::js/my.js"/>
    </head> 
</page>
```

In console, I am getting the error message

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How to fix this issue.

Comment: if using Requirejs, shouldn't use jQuery document ready: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332628/requirejs-domready-plugin-vs-jquery-document-ready

Comment: You should avoid adding JS this way, you should use Require JS within M2.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh great info

Comment: @Anshu Mishra did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @vbak I have already posted my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that there is no sequence tag defined in the `module.xml`. 
I have added `Magento_Theme` module in the `sequence` tag in my `module.xml` as follows

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
</sequence>
```

Secondly, I have added `requirejs-config.js` in my module's web directory.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            my: 'Custom_Module/js/my',
        }
    }
};
```

Third, I have modified the content of my js file as follows :

```
define('js/theme',['jquery', 'domReady!'], function(jQuery){
    alert('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 18):

Magento2 use **requirejs** concept (lazy load) so load jquery first  then write your jquery code.

e.g)

```
require(['jquery'],function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

       alert('ok');

    });

});
```

Comment: Using above code, I am getting TypeError: require is not a function

Comment: @AnshuMishra same thing is happening with me do you have any solution??

Answer (score 6):

We need to  use Requirejs to load the jQuery dependency. Your js should be:

*app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/js/my.js*

```
require([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {

   // your code here

});
```

Comment: Using above code, I am getting TypeError: require is not a function

Comment: Try to add the js in `default_head_blocks.xml`

Comment: Still getting the same error message, TypeError: require is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Yesterday everything worked just fine but the next day I suddenly get "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

I did no changes, I even checked out an older commit where everything worked fine.
It was because of a script which was not wrapped in `require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($){` ... even though the same script worked yesterday without it. Very strange.