# Add js to Widget

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

Hello looking for some help

I have created some Widget , and need to add in it JavaScript for **fetch instagram photos** 
I have a library and a script, but this script doesnt work.

I have added it in my `simplewidget.phtml`

but dont know how to write it correct in Magento2, maybe some one can help ? code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            userId: '5454117805',
            accessToken: '5454117805.1677ed0.a5cef727c5824160b3ee1238d053fadb',
            resolution: 'thumbnail',
            sortBy: 'most-recent',
            limit: 6,
            links: false
        });
        userFeed.run();
    });
</script>

<h1>Instagram Feed</h1>
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Comment: Please refer the answer, I hope it helps you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154649/36463

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: Just a heads up, you probably don't want to post  your Instagram accessToken :)

Comment: Updated with Facebook Graph API https://magecomp.com/magento-2-instagram-integration-pro.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add `JS` is with **requirejs**.

Assuming that your js file is: `instagram.js`

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/instagram'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/instagram.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert('Instagram ok'); //just for test
           jQuery(function() {
              var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                 get: 'user',
                 userId: '5454117805',
                 accessToken: '5454117805.1677ed0.a5cef727c5824160b3ee1238d053fadb',
                 resolution: 'thumbnail',
                 sortBy: 'most-recent',
                 limit: 6,
                 links: false
              });
              userFeed.run();
           });
       }
});
```

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/simplewidget.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
        myscript();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Strange that, when I do this:<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
       alert('ok');
    });
</script>      - it works, but when I write my code which one is on the top , it doesn't work. instagram.js there is a full function which should be called, when I write my above script with var elements. This is the full script library which is included in my header script not working: https://matthewelsom.com/assets/js/libs/instafeed.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","custom"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                userId: '5454117805',
                accessToken: '5454117805.1677ed0.a5cef727c5824160b3ee1238d053fadb',
                resolution: 'thumbnail',
                sortBy: 'most-recent',
                limit: 6,
                links: false
             });
            userFeed.run();
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Strange that, when I do this:<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function() { alert('ok'); }); </script> - it works, but when I write my code which one is on the top , it doesn't work. instagram.js there is a full function which should be called, when I write my above script with var elements. This is the full script library which is included in my header script not working: matthewelsom.com/assets/js/libs/instafeed.min.js